# Why we need permission on RBAC?

Tags: laravel, acl, access-control, rbac

I looking for RBAC for laravel, then i found something like sentinel, entrust, etc...

RBAC usually have 5 table like users, user_role, roles, role_permission, permissions.

If permissions depend on roles, why we not just check the roles, and delete that permissions table ?

Comment: Just to clarify your question, you want to know why we have to have the permissions table?

Comment: yes, as permission depend on role, so why we not only check that role?

Comment: How would you know what permissions the role has if you didn't have permissions?

Comment: just check that role, for.ex. if user has role admin then they can access admin page without check the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

You surely could get rid of permissions altogether, but you would still have to have them somewhere. Otherwise the roles would just degrade to permissions with another name.

Roles can have multiple permissions and users belong to roles. The code will still usually check for *permissions*, like "can edit settings", "can save" and the roles are just a grouping of permissions. For example, administrator can edit settings and save files.

If you only had roles, you would have to code the permissions in. Your code would say in every save point "is the user in role X or Y or Z?" and adding new roles would require adding them to code. So basically the roles would be pointless.

Comment: Agreed.  Checking roles (by name) in code is bad practice.  It leads to having to redeploy when security rules change, which is bad.  It also leads to large number of roles to be created, e.g. Role_Page1, Role_Page2, ... or one role for every resource.  Now, when users are assigned roles, dozens (if not hundreds) of roles must be assigned.